# display image whose link is in database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have links of images in my database e.g.-http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/images/products/large/330-5288.jpg
above link of an image is in one of the fields of my database. i don't know how to display it in my html page using php. Can any one help?
thnks

Comment: 4 answers and not one mention of `htmlspecialchars()` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT your_image FROM your_table WHERE your_conditions_here";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<img src="<?php echo $row['your_image']; ?>" />
<?php  
}
?>
```

Comment: you could make it Accepted answer if it suited your needs

Answer (score 1):

Have you already fetched the URL from the database? If so, just output it

```
<?php
    # code that fetches data from DB goes here...
?>
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

select the image's link from database. Now set the image src = value you selected from database.

```
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
```

Cheers...!!!

Comment: you may set height and width for the image..

<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" width="200px" height="auto">

btw, dont forget to accept the answer and vote for it.. ;)

Comment: can you further help me in putting the image from database into a table containing many rows/columns,ofcourse using php?

Answer (score 0):

Select the url, it will depend on your sql statement so if you have many url, make the variable array then store the url then output it. But in my example, I'm assuming that you only have one url then I put it on the variable $url so you can display it

```
 <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
      $result = myqsl_query($query);

      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $url = $row['url']
      }
 ?>


 <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
```